# break-inside css on an image in puppeteer is not shifting the rest of the content

Tags: javascript, css, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to generate PDFs. I have images in my page and I am using css

`break-inside: avoid;`

to avoid cutting images on page break. But whenever an image is shifted down because of this, it overlaps with the content after that (refer attached image)

[image: image overlapping with content]

Is there any way I can shift the rest of the content also? I tried giving

`display: block;`

to image but it didn't help.

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, can you update your question and share with us the relevant parts of code (HTML,CSS, etc.) that you are using and then we can try to identify the problem. Thank you

Comment: Isn't the image floated by any chance? I experienced similar problems with floated images

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to this, For break-inside to work, parent and child both has to have

`display: block`

my parent component had

`display:flex`

thats why it was not honouring break-inside.